# Angular test component is shown in the test window

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

When I run tests a strange thing is happening. By some reason components are shown in the DOM where the tests are. Also it's interesting that *only one* component is present at a time. It happens with every test which I have.

Screenshot shows the least disturbing case.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking a question?  Angular uses Karma and Jasmine together.  Karma launches a server and then a browser instance to attach to that server to graphically display the tests and results.  Typically unit tests create the components they are testing one at a time to test them, then destroy them before creating them again for the next test.  This can happen many times for a single component if it is tested many times.  Details on karma here: http://karma-runner.github.io/3.0/intro/how-it-works.html  Details on how Jasmine works are here: https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction

Comment: Yes I do. I need to figure out how to get rid of components in my tests, because some components like modal are shown over the content and it makes it not possible to even see the tests.

Answer (score 1):

When executing your component tests using Angular TestBed, the component under test will be attached to the test-runner's DOM allowing you to examine the DOM or simulate user interaction.

From the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics):

> A component, unlike all other parts of an Angular application,
> combines an HTML template and a TypeScript class. The component truly
> is the template and the class working together. To adequately test a
> component, you should test that they work together as intended.
>
> Such tests require creating the component's host element in the
> browser DOM, as Angular does, and investigating the component class's
> interaction with the DOM as described by its template.

The generated DOM element will not be removed automatically. However, you could remove it in afterEach() or afterAll().

```
describe("TestComponent", () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  });

  it("should have an awesome feature", () => {
    // ...
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(fixture.nativeElement);
  });
});
```

You can avoid creating the component's host element by testing the component class on its own as you would test a service class. This, of course, can only tell you about class behavior - no DOM integration or interaction.

```
describe("TestComponent", () => {
  it("should have an awesome feature", () => {
    const comp = new TestComponent();
    // ...
  });
});
```